# Cleaner way to find a list item within an array.

Tags: list-manipulation

So I have a list somewhat like this:

```
{
 {"name" -> "bob", "age" -> "20", "phone" -> "123456"},
 {"name" -> "Fred", "age" -> "40", "phone" -> "098765"}
}
```

At the moment I am doing the following to pull out the related item ( y is the list).

```
pos = First[First[Position[y, "Fred"]]]
z = Part[y, pos]
```

This returns:

```
{"name" -> "Fred", "age" -> "40", "phone" -> "098765"}
```

While "Fred" won't show up in other fields, I'm not overly happy with this.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to find an array item based on the value of a certain field within that array?

Comment: @Xavier, looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @Xavier Shape it in an answer and I'll vote on it. I tried that snippet you posted and it comes back with {} . I changed list to y.

Comment: Possibly a list of associations would be more appropriate in your application than a list of rules, i.e. `list = { <| "name" -> "bob", "age" -> "20", "phone" -> "123456" |>, <| "name" -> "Fred", "age" -> "40", "phone" -> "098765" |> }` Then you can do things like `list[[1]]["name"]` and `Select[list, #["name"] == "bob" &]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment posted as an answer, as suggested.

---

**Notation**

```
list = {
        {"name" -> "bob", "age" -> "20", "phone" -> "123456"},
        {"name" -> "Fred", "age" -> "40", "phone" -> "098765"}
       }
```

**Possible solutions**

If you are interested in getting `z` only, you can use

```
Cases[list, {_ -> "Fred", __}]
```

provided that the structure of all your sublists is the same as what you wrote. Alternatively, the function `Select` can be considered

```
Select[list, MatchQ[#, {_ -> "Fred", __}] &]
```

Those will give you all sublists where the name `Fred` occurs. In case there is only one item of this form, you will end up with `{z}` rather than `z`. A workaround would be

```
FirstCase[list, {_ -> "Fred", __}]
```

or

```
SelectFirst[list, MatchQ[#, {_ -> "Fred", __}] &]
```

**Update**

Following OP's comment, for a list of different structure one can use

```
 Cases[list, {___, "name" -> "Fred", ___}]
```

or

```
Select[list, MatchQ[#, {___, "name" -> "Fred", ___}] &]
```

Comment: `Select[list, ! FreeQ[#, "Fred"] &][[1]]`

Comment: @Xavier. They work for the example, but if you change the fields position they don't appear to always works. :-/ Bob's work for say phone number, but you haven't specified an explicit field. So there is chance another field could match.

Comment: Although not the exact answer helped me find the answer:  `Select[list, ! FreeQ[#, "name" -> "Fred"] &][[1]]`

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty See updated answer.

Comment: perfect! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The question is answered, but... one can also use a dataset to retrieve the information

```
{
 {"name" -> "bob", "age" -> "20", "phone" -> "123456"},
 {"name" -> "Fred", "age" -> "40", "phone" -> "098765"}
}
```

then

```
ds = Dataset@(Association /@ input)
```

Retrieve information:

```
Select[ds, #name == "Fred" &]
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping someone would post an Association answer. This is in my opinion the most natural way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: I've only recently started using associations, but I have been very impressed with its utility as a data structure.

Comment: Or `ds[Select[#name == "Fred" &]]`.

Comment: @Karsten7.: Indeed, this (your comment) is the way I use the Select command most offen ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This is a very natural solution that works in all versions of Mathematica:

```
x = {{"name" -> "bob", "age" -> "20", "phone" -> "123456"}, {"name" -> "Fred", "age" -> "40", "phone" -> "098765"}};

y = ("name" /. #) -> # & /@ x;

"Fred" /. y
(* Out: {"name" -> "Fred", "age" -> "40", "phone" -> "098765"} *)
```